# Parametros en funciones drag&drop

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda con el parametro 'e' dentro de las funciones. A que hace referencia esta variable.

```js
function iniciar() {
 var imagenes=document.querySelectorAll('#cajaimagenes>img');
 for (var i=0; i<imagenes.length; i++) {
  imagenes[i].addEventListener('Dragstart', arrastrado, false);
    }
  soltar=document.getElementById('cajasoltar');
  soltar.addEventListener('dragenter', function(e) { e.preventDefault;}, false);
  soltar.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) { e.preventDefault;}, false);
  soltar.addEventListener('dragend', soltado, false);
 }

 function arrastrado(e) { 
  elemento=e.target;
  e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', elemento.getAttribute('id'));

 }
```

Comment: Es el elemento que generó el evento.

Comment: @JDev al contrario, es el evento (hecho objeto) que se crea cuando haces un drag sobre el elemento. Dicho objeto contiene datos relevantes sobre el evento dragstart

Comment: Si eso, que me lie al intentar explicar que es el evento que incluye al elemento (e.target)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando el navegador detecta un evento como click, change, submit, over, scroll, dragstart... llama a la función asociada (event listener) pasando como parámetro un objeto que cumple la interfaz [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event).

Dependiendo del evento, el objeto podrá tener más o menos atributos, por ejemplo en el caso de *drag and drop*, tendrás un `DragEvent`, que hereda de `MouseEvent` (que a su vez hereda de `Event` y tiene más parámetros disponibles ([documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/DragEvent) sólo en inglés, lo siento)